# jQuery add a position:relative to my element using backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I have a strange trouble, i created a simple view using backbone.js :

```
class MyApp.Views.Tools.TextBox extends Backbone.View
  template: JST['pdfs/tools/text_box']

  tagName: "div"

  className: "resizable"

  id: "resizable"

  events:
    'click .close': 'closeRect'

  initialize: ->
    @

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template())
    @initDraggable()
    this

  initDraggable: ->
    $(@el).resizable().draggable();
    #$(@el).css({"position": "absolute"})
    @

  closeRect: (event) =>
    console.log "pass"
```

And my template:

```
<div class="close">x</div>
<input type="text" name="text_' + @count++ + '" />
```

When i do the line : $(@el).resizable().draggable();, jQuery add me a style="position:relative" to my element. I know why when i look the Draggable function on jQuery UI:

```
if (this.options.helper == 'original' && !(/^(?:r|a|f)/).test(this.element.css("position")))
this.element[0].style.position = 'relative';
```

But i don't understand why this.element.css("position") doesn't return my css property on the element : position:absolute.

Is it possible Backbone.js load javascript before css or doesn't use the css of my page?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); ?

Comment: Maybe, how can i do with backbone? The same as usual? I put it on the view? router?

Comment: wrap with (function(){ ... })()

Comment: it doesn't work, but i think the dom is loaded, because I does the Draggable on a click event on an element of my page.

Comment: Yes. Try to use my way of getting style so.
http://ruskevych.blogspot.com/2012/07/javascript-elements-style-properties.html

Comment: Not working :( I put in at the top of my javascript included.

Comment: try console.log(element) see if it contains array of elements or properties

Answer (score 0):

> But i don't understand why this.element.css("position") doesn't return my css property on the element : position:absolute.

I'm confused; as you pointed out jQuery draggable adds a `position: relative` style to its element.  Then, you had set it back to `"position": "absolute"` ... but you commented it out.

```
#$(@el).css({"position": "absolute"})
```

So, it seems like the reason it's still `relative` is that jQuery change it to `relative` and you never changed it back.